# How to Implement SSO in simple way?

Tags: single-sign-on

as the title says, this way [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211034/how-to-implement-sso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092222/1226787) seems too Tedious, is there any other simple way?

---

I find this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092222/1226787
AND 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10876984/1226787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of Single Sign On are you looking for? If you are using SAML based Single Sign On, then definitely use SimpleSAMLPHP: http://simplesamlphp.org/