# Accessing multiple projects on single sign on

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, liferay, single-sign-on, portal

i have a requirement to split my java project into 3 or 4 projects connected to same DB
Client do not want to down the server (for all modules )for a change in other modules.
Project is webapp deployed in Tomcat and that webapp communicates to EJBs in JBoss.

Authentication and authorization should be done once and there by the end user should be able to access all the projects after login screen. So I should use some SSO implementation.

Which technology i use along with SSO? Shall i go with portal technology, then is liferay is a good option? or JBoss Portal.
Does Java EE provides its own implementation for portal?
or is it possible without using portal technology?

Comment: I don't think you need a portal technology to have Single Sign-on for your already developed Web-applications.

Comment: The final setup would be like, we will be deploying 4 webapps along with EJBs in 4 JBoss servers.. One webapp should act as starting point with SSO. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. This [link](http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/) might help understand SSO better and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211034/how-to-implement-sso).